# more than one data query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a historical table on my oracle database.

I want to select only more than one record for the specific ID.

```
Select * from user_history
```

Table Structure:

```
ID History_Text
1  xxxxx
1  yyyyy
2  zzzzz
```

There are millions of records on the table. And I dont know the which ID has history.

For example: I only want to select has history, e.g ID=1 records.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very much clear. it is either very basic or a little complex.

if you want to select rows have id = 1 then use where clause

```
Select * from user_history where id = 1
```

if you want to select only those `ID` for which there are more than one record then use count function

```
select ID, History_Text from 
(Select ID, History_Text,count(*) over(partition by ID) cnt from user_history) t 
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple aggregation/counting with a condition on the aggregated value:

```
select id
from user_history
group by id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use where clause. Somthing like this:-

```
Select * 
from user_history
having count(id) = 2;
```

Comment: There are millions of records on the table. And I dont know the which ID has history.

Comment: Now see the edit part.

Comment: having clause without a group by?

Comment: Yes it will work......

Comment: did you even try the query?

Comment: Yes. I am sure it wil work.

Comment: No it will not work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2163e/1

Comment: HAVING Clause is used in combination with the GROUP BY Clause to restrict the groups of returned rows to only those whose the condition is TRUE.